# How to access key in Nested object in an array within a JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```js
var data = [
  {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
  }];

console.log(data.items[0].name === 'foo');
```

I am trying to access the key and checking if the value are same then return true or false, I am getting an error while accessing it.

Comment: Describe what error do you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is an array. It should be
`data[0].items[0].name`

```js
var data = [
  {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
  }];

console.log(data[0].items[0].name === 'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your data it should be like this

```
data[0].items[0].name === 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its `data[0].items[0].name`

- `data` is an array.
- `items` node in each node of `data` is also an array.

To access the zeroth node of `data` you have to use `data[0]` just same as you did with `items`

```js
var data = [
  {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
  }];

console.log(data[0].items[0].name === 'foo');
```